# How to access my web service from any where?

Tags: wcf

Just finish my first WCF service. 
I check it on my local network and all work fine.

Now, I want to give access to the web service from any where in the word.

How can i do it ?

Do i need just to add the web service to IIS as web site ? and with this way anyone in the word will be able to access the web service ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Publish your service on a public IP address.  It's the same concept as publishing a public web site.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to host the webservice on a server that is accessible to the public.